# How to write page headers when using iText library in java

Tags: java, itext

I am developing a report generation application that could have tabular data across multiple pages. I am using pdfTable to create tabular data. I am issues with adding page headers. The problem is that when I  add page header onEndPage event handler, I am not get the table to start after certain gap so that header is visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using tables  (PDFPTable) for your layout then you can use:   table.setHeaderRows(2);

JavaDoc Link : http://api.itextpdf.com/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfPTable.html

Comment: The requested URL /api/com/lowagie/text/pdf/PdfPTable.html was not found on this server.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out.  I updated the original.  Here is the new link  http://api.itextpdf.com/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfPTable.html

Answer (score 4):

If I understand this correctly, you just need to change your margins, so table will start after header.

From http://www.docjar.org/docs/api/com/lowagie/text/Document.html

```
public Document(Rectangle pageSize,
float marginLeft,
float marginRight,
float marginTop,
float marginBottom)
```

For example:

```
final Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 50, 50, 165, 50);
```